# Variable isn't updating

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function `setCoeff()` that's not updating the `coeff` variable, I think, because I'm not seeing any change in my `BadgeView`. How can I print what's coming out of that line? I have the `BadgeView` class defined in the `ViewController` file.

ViewController

```
if let ElapsedPercentual:Int = JSON.value(forKeyPath: "ResponseEntity.ElapsedPercentual") as? Int {
    porcentaje = ElapsedPercentual
    print(porcentaje)

    BadgeView().setCoeff(coeff: CGFloat(porcentaje)/100, animated: true) 
}
```

BadgeView

```
private(set) var coeff: CGFloat = 0.2 {
    didSet {
        updateFillViewFrame()
    }
}

public func setCoeff(coeff: CGFloat, animated: Bool) {
    if animated {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:{ () -> Void in
            self.coeff = coeff
        })
    } else {
        self.coeff = coeff
    }
}
```

**SOLVED:** I forgot to connect the UIView on the storyboard to the `ViewController`, then made it's type to be `BadgeView` then it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with `BadgeView().setCoeff(coeff: CGFloat(porcentaje)/100, animated: true)`. In this line, you are creating a new instance of `BadgeView` and calling a method on it. Not to the instance that is displayed in the UI.

Try to understand OOPs concepts, 
Refs:
https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html